# How to create an index using LibreOffice Calc (no macro)

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need to create a list of items in LibreOffice Calc, listing description and price; on another sheet I need to group specific items and make the line total.

My items list has the following IDs (1,2,4,8,...32,64,128,etc..) this way when I sum 2 or more items I obtain an unique ID, this ID so obtained describes of what elements it is composed in one line, so ID 7 is the sum of the first three.

I need to enter these ID in one sheet and lookup the total price on a near cell, let's make an example with numbers:

```
Sheet 1
 1 Price 10
 2 Price 35
 4 Price 80
 8 Price 16
16 Price  8
32 Price 29

Sheet 2
 7 Total Price 125
18 Total Price  43
35 Total Price  74
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly, but might give you something to develop. First the list in Sheet1 needs to be in reverse order. I added `64` in A1 (`0` in C1) then `32` in A2 etc.

In Sheet2 (where `7` is in A2 etc) in D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=BASE(A2,2,7)
```

(You might need to increase the `7`, depending upon how many `Total Price`s you have.)

Then on ColumnD Text to Columns..., Fixed width and parsed (Standard) at every character position.

Finally, in L2 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1.C$1:C$7,TRANSPOSE(D2:J2))
```